# Ruby Slim Lang: Onclick button triggers another onclick event

Tags: javascript, ruby, slim-lang

I have a "Let's Chat" button placed in a much better place rather than the "Reamaze Chat" chatbox.

How can I hook an onclick event on the "Let's Chat" button that uses slim,

```
  div.col-md-3
    p
      a.btn-primary.btn-lg.btn-block.chat-link Let's Chat
```

to open the ReAmaze chatbox triggered by an onclick action as well:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdn.reamaze.com/assets/reamaze.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var _support = _support || { 'ui': {}, 'user': {} };
  _support['account'] = 'scihelp';
  _support['ui']['widget'] = true;
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
  _support['user'] = {
    id: '<%= current_user.id %>',
    email: '<%= current_user.email %>',
    name: '<%= current_user.full_name %>',
    authkey: '<%= OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('sha256', "#{ENV['REAMAZE_SSO_SECRET']}", "#{current_user.id}:#{current_user.email}") %>'
  }
  <% end %>
  _support['custom_fields'] = {
    AppName: {
      type: 'hidden',
      value: 'Chat',
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Rather than modifying the click event, it would be much easier and clearer to call the additional js method within the original js method that is triggered by onclick.

Comment: @sawa the parent button must actually trigger the chatbox button to open the chatbox. There's basically a redundancy of buttons, I know, but UX wise - there's a "Let's Chat" button that should trigger opening the "Reamaze chatbox" button.

Comment: @sawa edited the question - must 've been unclear was writing in a hurry

Comment: This question is not about PHP Slim framework thus should not be tagged `slim`. The correct tag is `slim-lang`

Comment: @Nima sorry I'll change it I thought its the same! Thanks!